# Console Output to WindowBuilder GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I currently have a program that prints lines of text to the screen in 'System.out.println()' statements in different lines. I am new to Java, Eclipse and WindowBuilder.

I am now adding a GUI to this program. I was able to create the GUI with the buttons, which are working OK. My problem is that I want to print everything that prints to eclipse's console (or the command line) to a text box in my GUI instead in real time. How can I do this easily?

```
package Onur;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class BehaSendDFGUI extends JFrame {

    private BehaviourSendWithDF1 myAgent; // Reference to the agent class
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JDesktopPane desktopPane;
    private JButton btnMessage;
    private JButton btnMessage_1;
    private JButton btnMessage_2;
    private JButton btnMessage_3;
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public void setAgent(BehaviourSendWithDF1 a) {
        myAgent = a; // provide the value of the reference of BehaviourSendWithDF1 class here

    }

    private void updateTextArea(final String text) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textArea.append(text);
            }
          });
        }

        private void redirectSystemStreams() {
          OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
              updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
              updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
              write(b, 0, b.length);
            }
          };

          System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
          System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
        }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BehaSendDFGUI frame = new BehaSendDFGUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public BehaSendDFGUI() {


        setTitle("Behaviour Sender");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 523, 398);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mnFile.add(mntmExit);

        JMenu mnAbout = new JMenu("About");
        menuBar.add(mnAbout);

        JMenuItem mntmAboutThisGui = new JMenuItem("About This GUI");
        mnAbout.add(mntmAboutThisGui);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setFloatable(false);
        contentPane.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        toolBar.add(desktopPane);

        btnMessage = new JButton("Send Message 1");
        btnMessage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BehaviourSendWithDF1.STEP = "1";
                System.out.println("Button Pressed => STEP = " + BehaviourSendWithDF1.STEP );
                myAgent.behaSend();             
            }

        });
        btnMessage.setBounds(10, 11, 111, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnMessage);

        btnMessage_1 = new JButton("Send Message 2");
        btnMessage_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BehaviourSendWithDF1.STEP = "2";
                System.out.println("Button Pressed => STEP = " + BehaviourSendWithDF1.STEP );
                myAgent.behaSend(); 
            }
        });
        btnMessage_1.setBounds(131, 11, 111, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnMessage_1);

        btnMessage_2 = new JButton("Send Message 3");
        btnMessage_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                BehaviourSendWithDF1.STEP = "3";
                System.out.println("Button Pressed => STEP = " + BehaviourSendWithDF1.STEP );
                myAgent.behaSend(); 
            }
        });
        btnMessage_2.setBounds(252, 11, 111, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnMessage_2);

        btnMessage_3 = new JButton("Send Message 4");
        btnMessage_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                BehaviourSendWithDF1.STEP = "4";
                System.out.println("Button Pressed => STEP = " + BehaviourSendWithDF1.STEP );
                myAgent.behaSend(); 
            }
        });
        btnMessage_3.setBounds(373, 11, 111, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnMessage_3);

        JButton btnExitGui = new JButton("Exit GUI");
        btnExitGui.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        btnExitGui.setBounds(189, 293, 130, 23);
        desktopPane.add(btnExitGui);

        JTextPane txtpnConsoleOutput = new JTextPane();
        txtpnConsoleOutput.setText("Console Output:");
        txtpnConsoleOutput.setBounds(10, 45, 101, 20);
        desktopPane.add(txtpnConsoleOutput);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 76, 475, 206);
        desktopPane.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

        redirectSystemStreams();

    }
}
```

I have seen this solution on NetBeans but could not apply it for WindowBuilder:

http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2009/01/redirecting-systemout-and-systemerr-to.html

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT:** The working version of the code is edited in the question. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The solution, to redirect the System.out and System.err *is* the same, and this has absolutely nothing to do with NetBeans or WindowsBuilder or any other Swing windows-building utility and all to do with Swing. If that solution doesn't work for you, then you need tell us more including exactly how or why it's not working.

Comment: I try copying and pasting the code into Eclipse; but getting a lot of erros which I cannot solve.

Comment: Well of course you can't do that. Don't blindly copy and paste code ever, especially code you don't understand. Instead learn what the code is trying to do and use the concepts to write your own code. Your question needs to revolve more on what it is that you don't understand, else this question will not help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the code will work for sure, I wasn't so sure about that. I am partly getting what the code does, so now I can try playing with it. I cannot seem to 'textPane cannot be resolved' error by importing classes. I think the function name might have changed in later versions. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong just yet. Please show your code and the exact error message as well as indicating in the code which line is involved.

Comment: The part of code I borrowed from the website has the line 'Document doc = textPane.getDocument();'. Error: 'textPane cannot be resolved'. I think the issue is related to importing.

Comment: You need to show your code and the error message as an edit to your question, but yes, you will need to import the proper classes, but no that's not the cause of your error. The problem is that you don't have a variable in that scope named textPane. Again, you must borrow the *ideas* from the website, but not blindly copy code, because this is exactly what happens when you do.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong: it can't find a variable named "textPane". So again, where is this variable that you're trying to use? In fact where is *any* text component that can display text? Another strong recommendation: don't use a code generator such as Windows Builder or NetBean's Matisse until you understand Swing a bit better. You would benefit greatly by going through the Swing tutorials and learning about text components, how to use them, and how to use Swing in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems include

1. you're trying to use a variable that doesn't exist, textPane, and
2. your program doesn't have a text component that can display text. I suggest that you add a JTextArea in the least so you can redirect your output to it. Call it textPane if you desire, but whatever you call it, you at least need to have *something* that can display multiple lines of text.
3. Again, the general techniques that are described in the link you've provided are correct -- you need to redirect the System.out and System.err to an OutputStream of your creation,
4. but you have to take care to update Swing components only on the Swing event thread, hence the use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...})`...
5. So used correctly the article's recommendations *will* work. So keep at it.

Again, read the Swing tutorials and put aside the windows builder code generator. Code generators can be used to save you time, but if you use them before you have a good understand of the Swing library, you'll likely run into big problems any time you need anything more than the most basic GUI and behavior.

**Edit**
You appear to be trying to call `append(...)` on a JTextField, and this class does not allow that message. I suggest

- that you simplify your class greatly so it has only the most basic GUI to demonstrate redirecting of the System.out and err, and
- Again use a JTextArea, not a JTextField.

**Edit 2**
You ask:

> I couldn't solve the 'textArea.append(text);' scope error: textArea cannot be resolved.

Note where you ***declare*** the textArea variable. Since it is not declared in the class but rather in a method or constructor, it's not visible elsewhere in the class. The solution is to declare it in the class, not elsewhere.

**Edit 3**
For example,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RedirectOut extends JPanel {
   private static final int BUTTON_COUNT = 4;
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);
   private SomeAgent myAgent;

   public RedirectOut() {
      redirectSystemStreams();

      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

      for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_COUNT; i++) {
         final int count = i + 1;
         JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Send Message " + count){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               myAgent.setStep(String.valueOf(count));
               System.out.println("Button Pressed => STEP = "
                     + myAgent.getStep());
               myAgent.behaSend();
            }
         });
         JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
         btnPanel.add(button);
         add(btnPanel);
      }
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER));
   }

   public void setAgent(SomeAgent agent) {
      this.myAgent = agent;
   }

   public void updateTextArea(final String text) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            textArea.append(text);
         }
      });
   }

   private void redirectSystemStreams() {
      OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
         @Override
         public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
         }

         @Override
         public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
         }

         @Override
         public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            write(b, 0, b.length);
         }
      };

      System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
      System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      RedirectOut redirectOut = new RedirectOut();
      redirectOut.setAgent(new SomeAgent());

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("RedirectOut");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(redirectOut);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I got 1 and 2 and fixed. I do not get what you mean by number 4. I tried correcting the scope error and calling redirectSystemStreams() in the code some where after creating the text area. There are no compile errors, but the GUI gets stuck when I run it and doesn't print anything.

Comment: Also why are you using a JDesktopPane?

Comment: I used the JDesktoPane seeing it in a tutorial. Should I interchange it with another type? I try switching to JTextArea but somehow I am getting a scope error.

Comment: @OnurDogu: I would simply use a JPanel to hold my GUI. I would only use a JDesktopPane to display JInternalFrames. Also, where do you ever set your agent by calling `setAgent(...)`?

Comment: That is done in another class, in the separate agent file. That part of code does not have a problem working. Without the GUI printing everything works fine. I couldn't solve the 'textArea.append(text);' scope error: textArea cannot be resolved.

Comment: @OnurDogu: show your latest code.

Comment: I have already updated the code in the question. textArea varible is not recognized from the textArea creation.

Comment: @OnurDogu: see edit 2 and edit 3 (for example)

Comment: I got it working, thank you so much for all the help. However, right now everything is just printed on the GUI. Is there any easy way to also keep it on the console?